# VBA Else without if error

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting the " Else without if" error in VBA when I clearly do not have that issue. Does anyone know how to fix it? It takes me to the elseif statement that begins with elseif memb= "platinum" 
Below is my code:

```
ElseIf memb = "Platinum" Then d = 0.01

ElseIf memb = "Black" Then d = 0.03

End If

If st >= min Then cb = st * d Else cb = 0
End If
If cb >= thresh Then MsgBox ("cb is greater than thresh")
End If

tac = st + cb

Range("B5").Value = st
Range("B7").Value = cb
Range("B9").Value = tac
```

Comment: It wouldn't allow me to post my line right before the elseifmeb = "platinum" line. I begun my if before that.

Comment: VB.NET is not the same as VBA.

Comment: Without the line before the `ElseIf`, we probably can't help answer your question.  (But if it says something like `If something Then something` then you can't have an `ElseIf` after a "single-line" `If`.  Just as you can't have an `End If` after your later "single-line" `If` statements such as `If st >= min Then cb = st * d Else cb = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume your first `If` statement goes something like this:

```
If memb = "Gold" Then d = 0.005

ElseIf memb = "Platinum" Then d = 0.01

ElseIf memb = "Black" Then d = 0.03

End If
```

If some processing is performed on the same line as the `Then` keyword, VBA treats it as a single, non-nested `If` statement. This means that anything after that will be treated as a new statement and not related to prior `If` statement.

What you can do is put the processing statement(s) on the next line after each `If-Then` and `ElseIf-Then` statements.

Example,

```
If memb = "Gold" Then
  d = 0.005
ElseIf memb = "Platinum" Then
  d = 0.01
ElseIf memb = "Black" Then
  d = 0.03
End If
```

With this in mind, you may want to fix the succeeding `If-Then-Else` statements in your code. The `End If` part becomes meaningless if your `If-Then-Else` is in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have syntax error and error message tells you that.
Or you did not post all code?

Have a look on MS documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/752y8abs.aspx

Do you really stick to the syntax?

Without even having MS OFfice this should (be better readable and) work:

```
If memb = "Platinum" Then
  d = 0.01
ElseIf memb = "Black" Then
  d = 0.03
End If

If st >= min Then
  cb = st * d
Else
  cb = 0
End If

If cb >= thresh Then
  MsgBox ("cb is greater than thresh")
End If

tac = st + cb

Range("B5").Value = st
Range("B7").Value = cb
Range("B9").Value = tac
```